# Python data unicode conversion

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following list:

```
list = [u'0', u'FF', u'7', u'0', u'FF', u'FFF', u'FFF']
```

and I need to use the elements as integer or float but when I try convevrting I get the following error:

```
>>> float(list[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: FF
```

Is there any way of solving this?

Comment: what are you expecting when converting `FF` to float? Are you looking for hexadecimal conversion?

Answer (score 3):

You can not convert that hex values to `float` directly, instead you can convert to int with specifying a proper base using `int()` function :

```
>>> l = [u'0', u'FF', u'7', u'0', u'FF', u'FFF', u'FFF']
>>> [int(i,16) for i in l]
[0, 255, 7, 0, 255, 4095, 4095]
```

Or use `float` on `int` values :

```
>>> [float(int(i,16)) for i in l]
[0.0, 255.0, 7.0, 0.0, 255.0, 4095.0, 4095.0]
```